# Using ambassador ingress controller in kubernetes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, ambassador

I have created my auth service deployed in a kuberenetes  cluster which is working and generating token when api is called by node port. I wanted to use Ambassador as the ingress controller so I mapped my services with ambassador but now when i call my auth service im getting

Spring Boot: RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String “//”

I tried changing to nginx and it worked fine. Any suggestion why Im getting spring boot http firewall exception in ambasador

```yaml
apiVersion: getambassador.io/v2
kind: AuthService
metadata:
  name: authentication
spec:
  auth_service: "auth:3000"
  path_prefix: "/extauth"`
```

Comment: What if you delete path_prefix?  Maybe you could try to use [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11895#issuecomment-491238122)? If you use an [example](https://www.getambassador.io/docs/latest/howtos/basic-auth/) from ambassador docs it works?

Comment: Tried without the path_prefix and I used the docs example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a slash at the end of the prefix string.ie,path_prefix: "/extauth/"

Comment: this should be a comment, instead of an answer. Unless you know that's the reason.